# Cannot check certificates for APNS connection

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to setup push notification with APNS and Amazon SNS. Now I am trying to test whether my certificates can connect to APNS. I based it from this article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools

Now, since the private key is in .p12 form, I converted it to .pem form with this code:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

It worked and generated a new .pem file. Now, I just use this line to check:

```
openssl s_client -connect "api.sandbox.push.apple.com":443 -cert "./aps_development.cer" -certform DER -key "Certificates.pem" -keyform PEM
```

It failed with this error code:

```
error setting private key
8445247808:error:0BFFF074:x509 certificate routines:CRYPTO_internal:key values mismatch:...
```

The funny thing is, both certificate and private key can be used in Amazon SNS's console. So I guess they are actually valid. What did I do wrong here? Thank you.